# What was the most common pronunciation of the interjection "io" in Classical Latin?

Tags: pronunciation

Wiktionary lists [two pronunciations for *io*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/io#Latin):

> /ˈi.oː/, [ˈioː]

Was one more common than the other? And just so I'm clear, the first would sound something like *ee-oh* in English, and the second *yo*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both of them are the same thing, and are pronounced the same way. It is just a matter of how to write it down. The left one, /ˈi.oː/, is phonemic transcription, showing the phonemes of the sound system of the language. The right one, [ˈioː], is phonetic transcription, showing the actual pronunciation. This means that phonetic transcription is more detailed.

As you wrote, *ee-oh* is probably the best approximation how to say it in English. Although, phonetically most English speakers say it [ˈiːoʊ], which is not the same as the pronunciation of *io!*.